# Open node on mouse click

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I added even handler for TreeView but I noticed one problem when I click on a tree node.

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel>>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel>> observable, TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> oldValue, TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> newValue)
    {
        // Some action
    }
});
```

I'm using the default TreeView in JavaFX. I can execute one mouse click action only once. In order to perform second time mouse click operation on the same tree node I need to click near tree node and to click again on the node that I want to open. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You are not really listening for mouse clicks at all - you are listening for changes in the selected item. Clicking a second time on the already selected item does not change what is selected. Instead, create a custom cell and register a mouse listener on the cell.

Comment: The [standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-view.htm#BABDEADA) has an example of creating a custom cell. You don't need anything that complicated, just set the text and register a mouse listener.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140954/how-can-i-right-click-on-a-cell-in-tableview-in-javafx-fxml, which is basically solved by the same technique.