# Addition of content by clicking mouse on a row of a TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, uitableview

I have TableView say "TV" containing three columns say "C1", "C2" and "C3". I have an ObservableArrayList say "d1" which initially is blank. *I want to right click on C1 of a row say "Row 3",* then a popup window will appear with a TextField, "accept" and "cancel" buttons. After usual entry in textField and acceptance, *the content will be added in the C2 of that corresponding row with updated d1.*

I am unable to use rightclick and updation of TV and d1.

There are many queries much like this question while the difference is I do not have any button to edit/select etc. Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I right click on a cell in tableview in Javafx (fxml)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140954/how-can-i-right-click-on-a-cell-in-tableview-in-javafx-fxml)

Comment: @purringpigeon, I have seen that. Beside right click stuffs, I need to update the ArrayList d1.  I can't update that.