# JavaFX: add contextmenu to TableView cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a context menu for every individual cell in a column, that gets activated by rightclicking on the cell. The menuitems would also depend on the cell clicked.

I would think using a cell factory would be the best way, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Edit: This is my implementation for one of my columns. setText in updateItem() adds the text to my column, but I want to add it as a label, how should I do that?

```
moColumn = new TableColumn<>("Maandag");
    moColumn.setSortable(false);
    moColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Mo"));
    getColumns().add(moColumn);
    moColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<RowData, Label>, TableCell<RowData, Label>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<RowData, Label> call(TableColumn<RowData, Label> col) {
            final TableCell<RowData, Label> cell = new TableCell<RowData, Label>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty){
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getText());
                    }
                }
            };

            //cell.textProperty().bind(cell.getItem().textProperty());

            cell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
                        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(cell.getText());
                        contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);
                        cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                    }
                }
            });
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Edit: [How can I right click on a cell in tableview in Javafx (fxml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140954/how-can-i-right-click-on-a-cell-in-tableview-in-javafx-fxml) 
I've found this, but the link to the blog isn't working anymore...

Comment: Implement the cell factory as shown in the linked question, and add a context menu to it. If you have a specific problem with your attempted implementation, create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I just clicked the link. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Sedrick The link has been edited out by James before you saw his answer.

Comment: @James_D I've added my implementation, binding my textproperty doens't work.

Comment: also, don't add controls as data ...

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
@Override
            protected void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty){
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getText());
                }
            }
```

To:

```
@Override
            protected void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty){
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: is this a riddle? - I fail to see a difference between the two snippets (being in lazy Sunday mood, though could well be my missing something :)

Comment: Oops, my bad. The setGraphic(item); is the difference, sorry